# ASP.net MVC 4 Unit Testing Viewbag/ViewModel test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I'm new to unit testing/mvc in .net. I have been following along with the book Pro ASP.net MVC 4, 4th edition. In the book they create a fake store. In one of the examples they pass data to a partial view using viewbag. They have an associating unit test that works, however I rewrote the example to pass the data through a view model instead of the viewbag container and now I can't seem to figure out a way to rewrite the unit test to pass. Anyone mind helping me out? I just am trying to figure this out for an hour and its a losing effort. The following is the  WORKING test.

```
// Arrange
// - create the mock repository
Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
    new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "P1", Category = "Apples"},
    new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "P2", Category = "Oranges"},
}.AsQueryable());

// Arrange - create the controller
NavController target = new NavController(mock.Object);

// Arrange - define the category to selected
string categoryToSelect = "Apples";

// Action
string result = target.Menu(categoryToSelect).ViewBag.SelectedCategory;

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(categoryToSelect,result);
```

So now that I have passed the data (successfully) through a view model...

```
public class CategoryInfoViewModel:IEnumerable<string>
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Categories.GetEnumerator();
    } 

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    } 
}
```

How can I change the test to make it work? Thanks much fellas!

Comment: What behavior is your test supposed to test?

Comment: I am trying to assert that the SelectedCategory is correct.

Comment: // Action string result=target.Menu(categoryToSelect).ViewBag.SelectedCategory;

Comment: I gotta be honest... I'm not a big fan of these kinds of tests.  There's no business logic being employed here; the test is merely asserting that a category has been selected.  You're essentially testing the framework, and that had damn well better be working already.  The test is a whole lot of ceremony for not very much benefit.

Comment: Completely follow you on that Robert, however this is more for my knowledge to understand how to access a model property in a unit test. Frustrating the crap out of me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the return type of action is a ViewResult, you could use the following code:

```
// Arrange
// - create the mock repository
Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
    new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "P1", Category = "Apples"},
    new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "P2", Category = "Oranges"},
}.AsQueryable());

// Arrange - create the controller
NavController target = new NavController(mock.Object);

// Arrange - define the category to selected
string categoryToSelect = "Apples";

// Action
string result = (ViewResult)target.Menu(categoryToSelect);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(categoryToSelect,result.Model);
```

I hope this works for you.
Regards,

Comment: Still no dice but thanks for the input. Menu is a partialviewresult if that helps. Casting ViewResult != string though either. Man this is frustrating me lol

Comment: So do the type casting to PartialViewResult

string result = (PartialViewResult)target.Menu(categoryToSelect);

Comment: Augusto see my answer above. Thanks for the reply that gave me the insight. Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out. I'm a bonehead. The view model class I made is called CategoryInfoViewModel. So I had to do this...

```
 // Action
 CategoryInfoViewModel result = (CategoryInfoViewModel)target.Menu(categoryToSelect).Model;

 // Assert
 Assert.AreEqual(categoryToSelect, result.SelectedCategory);
```